# Get an integer array from an xml resource in Android program

Tags: java, android

Just a quickie,

i have an xml resource in res/values/integers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
     <integer-array name="UserBases">
          <item>2</item>
          <item>8</item>
          <item>10</item>
          <item>16</item>
     </integer-array>
</resources>
```

and ive tried several things to access it:

```
int[] bases = R.array.UserBases;
```

this just returns and int reference to UserBases not the array itself

```
int[] bases = Resources.getSystem().getIntArray(R.array.UserBases);
```

and this throws an exception back at me telling me the int reference R.array.UserBases points to nothing

what is the best way to access this array, push it into a nice base-type int[] and then possibly push any modifications back into the xml resource.

I've checked the android documentation but I haven't found anything terribly fruitful.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You need to use Resources to get the int array; however you're using the system resources, which only includes the standard Android resources (e.g., those accessible via `android.R.array.*`).  To get your own resources, you need to access the Resources via one of your Contexts.

For example, all Activities are Contexts, so in an Activity you can do this:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int[] bases = r.getIntArray(R.array.UserBases);
```

This is why it's often useful to pass around Context; you'll need it to get a hold of your application's Resources.

Comment: Cool Beans! Thanks a lot.

also whats the best way to add and remove items from the array (save editing raw xml) - essentially updating any changes from the int[] to the xml.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible to update the xml from code; all resources xml is compiled into binary when you build the apk.  You should make a new question on it, maybe someone else knows.

Answer (score 0):

get an array from xml resources of android project can be accessed.

from array.xml

```
<string-array name="weather_values">
    <item>sunny</item>
    <item>cloudy</item>
    <item>rainy</item>
</string-array>
```

in Activity

```
String[] stringsArray = getApplicationContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weather_values);
```

in Fragment

```
String[] stringsArray = getContext().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weather_values);
```

for output in log

```
System.out.println("Array Values " + Arrays.toString(stringsArray));
```

output is

```
I/System.out: Array Values [sunny, cloudy, rainy]
```