# Get array of id drawable resources

Tags: android, resources, drawable

I need many similar drawable resources.
I created the files necessary to me in the drawable folder
Then the file of resources with the array:

```
<array name="btn_style">
    <item>@drawable/tile0</item>
    <item>@drawable/tile1</item>
    ...
</array>
```

But when I write

```
int[] btn_draw = getResources().getIntArray(R.array.btn_style);
```

I receive zero from the array.

If I do

```
  int[] btn_draw = {R.drawable.tile0,R.drawable.tile1};
```

All works fine.

Comment: I din't get what you are asking can you explain what do you want

Comment: `I receive the array from zero.` - Yes, correct, the array starts at index 0.

Comment: I want to receive array of ID resources, instead of array of zero.
I found workaround, but I want to understand why so occurs.

Comment: `I receive the array from zero.` I believe the OP meant that he received a value of zero from the array. I've edited the question to clarify. @OP: I'm guessing the reason you received the wrong value using `getIntArray()` was that your XML uses `<array>` instead of `<integer-array>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question.. here is your answer:

**try this:** 
  You can use typed array..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>

        <string-array name="random_imgs">
            <item>@drawable/car_01</item>
            <item>@drawable/balloon_random_02</item>
            <item>@drawable/dog_03</item>
        </string-array>

    </resources>
```

Then in your activity access them like so:

```
TypedArray imgs = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.random_imgs);
//get resourceid by index
imgs.getResourceId(i, -1)
// or set you ImageView's resource to the id
mImgView1.setImageResource(imgs.getResourceId(i, -1));
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont have the reputation to comment your question so I have to post an answer.

This question I believe has already been answered:

[Get an integer array from an xml resource in Android program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064595/get-an-integer-array-from-an-xml-resource-in-android-program)

Comment: I do as it is written in this example. But in a my case it doesn't work with drawable.