# Kotlin get string from resources by index

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and i'm stuck at trying to access a string array from my resources.
I have a string array in my strings.xml file and i want to extract a string from it by index.
I'm using a spinner for selecting the index:

```
    override fun onItemSelected(
        parent: AdapterView<*>?,
        view: View?,
        position: Int,
        id: Long
    ) {
        titleTextView.text = R.array.content[position]
    }
```

When i try to pass the position parameter as my array index, i get an error telling me i have no get method for array access.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `R.array.content` is a resource identifier, not the resource itself. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2064595/get-an-integer-array-from-an-xml-resource-in-android-program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `R.array.content` take the whole string inside a string array.

```
val stringArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.(your array name));
```

then make use of this stringArray to access individual elements using the position.

Answer (score 2):

First declare a instance variable for array from string resource:

```
private val contentArray by lazy { resources.getStringArray(R.array.content) }
```

In the onItemSelected get the value like below using the `position`:

```
override fun onItemSelected(
    parent: AdapterView<*>?,
    view: View?,
    position: Int,
    id: Long
) {
    titleTextView.text = contentArray[position]
}
```